# Displaying data in a table using angular 5

Tags: angular

I'm trying to display data in a table I got the part from HTML working because I use to keep it empty and data will be shown when I do a search
I want to change that to display data when I load the page and the table will be full.

this is my service : 
userservice.ts :

```
public getUserss() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8081' + '/users');
}
```

users.component.ts: this is where I need to implement the code: it's wrong

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userservice.getUserss().subscribe();
}
```

the table that I want to display is a html table not material table :

```
  <table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Password</th>
    <th>Role</th> <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let u of pageUsers?.content">
    <td>{{u.id}}</td>
    <td>{{u.nom}}</td>
    <td>{{u.prenom}}</td>
    <td>{{u.email}}</td>
    <td>{{u.username}}</td>
    <td>{{u.password}}</td>
    <td>{{u.role}}</td>
    <td>
      <button style="color: #4CAF50;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" (click)="onEditUser(u.id)" ></button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button style="color: red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" (click)="deleteuser(u)" ></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I just want to know how to change my service and my component to display data on init

JSON

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nom": "SBOUI",
    "prenom": "sameh",
    "email": "samehsboui_enicar@gmail.com",
    "username": "sameh",
    "password": "sameh",
    "role": "admin"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nom": "ORANGE",
    "prenom": "",
    "email": "orange@yahoo.com",
    "username": "OrangeIP",
    "password": "orange140",
    "role": "client"
  },
  {
    "id": 37,
    "nom": "try2name",
    "prenom": "try2 ",
    "email": "try@gmail.com",
    "username": "try158",
    "password": "zkndgkji",
    "role": "client"
  }
]
```

Comment: what is the reponse of the api call? Can you add the response json to the question?

Comment: [{"id":1,"nom":"SBOUI","prenom":"sameh","email":"samehsboui_enicar@gmail.com","username":"sameh","password":"sameh","role":"admin"},{"id":3,"nom":"ORANGE","prenom":"","email":"orange@yahoo.com","username":"OrangeIP","password":"orange140","role":"client"},{"id":37,"nom":"try2name","prenom":"try2 ","email":"try@gmail.com","username":"try158","password":"zkndgkji","role":"client"}]

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the values

```
this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
        this.pageUsers = users;
});
```

Comment: you need to check what you are getting when you do console.log(this.pageUsers);

Answer (score 1):

You need to incorporate `async` pipe in your HTML code. This is because your data is asynchronous and you do not save it in a variable in your ts after subscribing to it.

So HTML does not know that this data would be available after a delay. Hence use the `async` pipe.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th>Role</th> <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let u of (pageUsers | async).content">
        <td>{{u.id}}</td>
        <td>{{u.nom}}</td>
        <td>{{u.prenom}}</td>
        <td>{{u.email}}</td>
        <td>{{u.username}}</td>
        <td>{{u.password}}</td>
        <td>{{u.role}}</td>
        <td>
          <button style="color: #4CAF50;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" (click)="onEditUser(u.id)" ></button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="color: red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" (click)="deleteuser(u)" ></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an array for the response. So you can do just like this.

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {
      this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
            this.pageUsers = users;
      });
   }
```

---

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Password</th>
    <th>Role</th> <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let u of pageUsers">
    <td>{{u.id}}</td>
    <td>{{u.nom}}</td>
    <td>{{u.prenom}}</td>
    <td>{{u.email}}</td>
    <td>{{u.username}}</td>
    <td>{{u.password}}</td>
    <td>{{u.role}}</td>
    <td>
      <button style="color: #4CAF50;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" (click)="onEditUser(u.id)" ></button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button style="color: red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" (click)="deleteuser(u)" ></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

change `let u of pageUsers?.content` to `let u of pageUsers`